# Java thread start time

Tags: java, multithreading, time, jvm

Is it possible to retrieve the start time of a given java thread within the JVM?

I have a thread dump and am looking at some problematic threads which I would like to correlate to a specific operations in the application log using time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you are running Oracle JDK / OpenJDK on Linux.

The idea is to find native thread id (TID) and then look at the modification time of `/proc/JAVA_PID/task/TID` pseudo file.

If you have a Thread Dump, then this is trivial: the native thread id would be printed by the thread header.

For example, Java process PID is 2086. You type

```
$ jstack 2086
```

and get a stack trace with the following thread of interest:

```
"Thread-26" prio=10 tid=0x00007f96c80c2800 nid=0x86a waiting on condition [0x00007f96c0ff2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
```

Where `nid=0x86a` is the native thread ID. 0x86a = 2154, so you'd like to explore task 2154 of the process 2086:

```
$ ls -ld /proc/2086/task/2154
dr-xr-xr-x 6 user user 0 Mar 10 23:12 /proc/2086/task/2154
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         the thread start time
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I am not quite understanding the explanation however.  I do have a thread dump.  Is there a TID pseude file for each thread?  If you could provide an example, that would be great.

Comment: @bobdabelina I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Hello, I tried this approach but I always see that the the time stamp is set to the current time.  Is there anything else to consider?

Comment: @bobdabelina Try `stat /proc/PID/task/TID` or `ls -l /proc/PID/task/TID` to list all pseudofiles related to the thread. Do they all have the same current timestamp?

Answer (score 4):

There is no method in the Java API that provides you this information. Besides, it may not be up useful anyways. Consider the case of a thread pool where thread creation is not necessarily tied to application-level events.

If you are in full control of thread creation, then you may attach a thread-local variable to the thread that records its creation time.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I  believe that these threads are being invoked by user requests.  Unfortunately I don't have the ability to modify code at this moment and have to work with whatever is running on production currently.

Comment: Are they created by a container (e.g. An app server) or your application code is creating them?

Comment: They are created by the container.

Answer (score 1):

try using "ps -p $pid -wLo lwp,lstart"